# Is there a way to at top of SQL query create code that will change a date referenced multiple times in code?

Tags: sql, teradata

Sorry for the extra long title but I am having trouble describing the question.

Essentially I have a code that links a bunch of tables together and I have the same date used probably 10 times throughout the code to limit the amount of data I am looking into.

I will have to change the date sometimes and all 10 will be changed to the same date again. Is there some sort of code that at the top/bottom of code I can just change it once and have the other dates read off that or something? Or is only way to change each individual date separately.

I imagine some way of putting in place of the date "x" and then at top or bottom of query saying x = 2016-01-01

I tried searching this but never got what I was looking for. I tried a declare but I must not be using it correctly if that is how it works...

### Thanks in advance and sorry for the long question!

In some of the comments I was asked more questions, honestly, I am fairly new and not sure what 'SQL' im using, I use Teradata SQL Assistant as my program if that means anything to anyone?

Also, for some sample coding this is what im essentially trying to do

select
1
2
3
4

from xtable

where effective_date > '2016/01/01'

I do this in many different fashions but would love something that I could do so the '2016/01/01' equals effdate and then somewhere above I can set effdate = '2016'/01/01' and have the table now read

select
1
2
3
4

from xtable

where effective_date > effdate

hope this adds some clarity? I have tried doing a declare @ or set, can't seem to get language correct...

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (e.g.: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, a small sample of code would help convey what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Most SQL dialects support the use of variables, one way or the other.  However, I find that I sometimes use a CTE for this purpose:

```
with params as (
      select cast('2016-01-01' as date) as thedate
     )
select . . .
from params cross join
     . . .
```

Because `params` has only one row, I haven't seen it affect the query plan.  Sometimes, it needs to be repeated in a subquery:

```
with params as (
      select cast('2016-01-01' as date) as thedate
     )
select . . .
from params cross join
     table1 . . .
     (select . . 
      from params cross join
           . . .
     ) s
     on . . .
```

CTEs (the `with` statement) is ANSI standard and supported by almost all databases.

Comment: +1. The list of "almost all databases" that support Common Table Expressions still (frustratingly) excludes MySQL.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . On the other hand, MySQL is rather flexible with variables and similar functionality is usually possible by defining variables in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, you may be able to make use of an inline view. As an example:

```
SELECT fum.fee
  FROM (SELECT '2016-01-12' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS mydate) i 
  JOIN fum
    ON fum.fi < i.mydate
   AND fum.fo > i.mydate
```

For MySQL, you can also use a user-defined variable. The value of a user-defined variable is persisted at the session level.

A value can be set as a separate statement, and the query can reference that multiple times:

```
SET @mydateval = '2016-01-13'

SELECT fum.fee 
  FROM fum
 WHERE fum.fi < @mydateval
   AND fum.fo > @mydateval
```

It's also possible to assign a value to a user-defined variable within a statement (for example, using an inline view). A reference to the variable returns the value that is currently assigned (at the time the reference is evaluated). The MySQL Reference Manual documents warnings about the behavior.

If you set the value of the variable in one statement, and then reference it in another statement, it will be fine, as long as there isn't something else that modifies the value of the user-defined variable, like a user-defined function.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, very simple and wouldn't mess up the rest of my code (new to sql here). My question is, I get an error when doing this saying I need something between set and @...